# How to display product info from an array in react?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I would like to render a div block for each product name in an array. I am getting a list of products from an api which contains product name and cost. The following piece of code works if i try to list the elements but I would like to put these products in a preexisting div block i created.

```
function Basket() {
    
     const[prods, setProds] = useState([])
    

     function refreshList(){
         
            fetch("http://localhost:60036/api/Product")
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                setProds(data);
            })
        }
        
    useEffect(() => {
        refreshList()
    }, []);

return (
    <>  
    <div>
       <ul>
           {
               prods.map(prod => <li> {prod.ProductName}</li>)
           }
        </ul>
    </div>
    </>
)
}

export default Basket;
```

The above works well and prints the product name and id. However, I want a **basket-product** to be created for each product name in the list returned from the call in the following div block which I want to insert in the return. I have some static product names now.

```
<div className="basket">
    <div className="basket-product">
        <div className="item">
            <div className="product-image">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/120x166" alt="Placholder Image 2" className="product-frame" />
            </div>
            <div className="product-details">
                <h1>
                    <strong><span className="item-quantity">4</span> x Eliza J</strong> Lace Sleeve Cuff Dress
                </h1>
                <p><strong>Navy, Size 18</strong></p>
                <p>Product Code - 232321939</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="price">26.00</div>
        <div className="quantity">
            <input type="number" defaultValue="{4}" min="{1}" className="quantity-field" />
        </div>
        <div className="subtotal">104.00</div>
        <div className="remove">
            <button>Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update return statement like this

```
return (
  <div className="basket">
    {prods.map(prod => (
      <div key={prod.id} className="basket-product">
        {prod.ProductName} // here you can add the other jsx code aswell
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Hi @brijesh-pant. I just thought of something which I would like to include. Is it possibly to increment just the count if the item is thesame? lets say I had the item twice. Because the above code will add more divs for thesame item

Comment: @Leroi I'm not sure I understand your question well. Can you share more what you're trying to do?

Comment: If you look in the div block in the second part of the question there is a defaultValue="{4}". I am getting the product information now from an api. I will like to increment the default value by 1 if we have thesame item twice from the fetched data. I do not know if that needs to be done from the react app point of view or from the api. From the above answer, the item is added separately on the UI. Btw it is a microfrontend architecture. The product page is developed in ASP.NET and the cart is developed in react and they are communicating over the web api.

Comment: @Leroi Check the answer I've shared below

Answer (score 0):

// **To answer:** If you look in the div block in the second part of the question there is a defaultValue="{4}". I am getting the product information now from an api. I will like to increment the default value by 1 if we have thesame item twice from the fetched data.

In that case, you need to filter the list of data you get from the response, something like a code I've shared below. When filtering the data you can change the defaultValue to new value by increment/decrement it. An example

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-hamilton-w5plf?file=/src/App.js

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Noodles" },
  { id: 2, name: "Pasta" },
  { id: 1, name: "Noodles" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [prods, setProds] = React.useState([]);

  function refreshList() {
    // filter here the response data you get from the API before setting it to component state
    const filteredData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc.some(({ id }) => id === curr.id)) {
        return acc;
      }
      acc.push(curr);
      return acc;
    }, []);
    setProds(filteredData);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    refreshList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {prods.map(prod => (
            <li> {prod.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think this will work if I use the productName rather than the id since in my case the products  in the fetched data could have different Ids but same name. I will check on how i can get the count of products that are repetitive and add that to the default value. Thanks

Comment: @Leroi The main thing is you filter the data first (whatever your filter logic can be), and, then render it.